# Manipulate string containing parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, recursion, pyparsing

Say I have a string like this,

`"(a=1) and ((b=2) or (c=3))"`

Where ever there is **"and"** i need to do convert it to this in python,

`"query[(a=1)].add(query[(b=2) or (c=3)])"`

as you can see there are two things happening,
when ever i am doing **add** i am wrapping operands with query[] and i am converting `a and b` to `a.add(b)`.

One more example if the string is like,

`"(a=1) and ((b=2) and (c=3))"` where there are two and's

the result should be,

`"query[(a=1)].add(query[(b=2)].add(query[(c=3)]))"`

I cannot hard code this, because the parentheses could be of any nested level.

The expression i have shown above is simplified one for explaination, it could be like this also,

`'((Attributes.name=="usertype") & (cast(User_Values.value, db.String())=='"Employee"')) and (((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"type":"examplecom"}]))) or ((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"value":"exampleorg"}]))))'`

**Progres**:-

Was trying to use "pyparsing" library to to get outer brackets content of operands.

```
ms = '((Attributes.name=="usertype") & (cast(User_Values.value, db.String())=='"Employee"')) and (((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"type":"examplecom"}]))) and ((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"value":"exampleorg"}]))))'

scanner = originalTextFor(nestedExpr('(',')'))

for match in scanner.searchString(ms):
    print("match is ..........", match[0])
```

got this,

```
((Attributes.name=="usertype") & (cast(User_Values.value, db.String())==Employee))
(((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"type":"examplecom"}]))) and ((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"value":"exampleorg"}]))))
```

next i am looking to get outermost parentheses content of operands of **and**.
That is not happening in the above example. Its just giving two independent parentheses content.

**Edit on 8th October 2020**

The solution by Ken T makes sense, but i notice an issue there.

`"((b=2) and (c=3)) and (a=1)"` where there are two and's

the result should be,

`"query[(b=2)].add(query[(c=3)]).add(query[(a=1)])"`
but the result is,

```
query[((b=2)].add(query[c=3)) and (a=1])
```

Example,

for input,

```
'(((Values.attribute=="1") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like('"%a%"'))) and ((Values.attribute=="3") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like('"%b%"')))) and ((Values.attribute=="1") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like('"%a%"')))'
```

The expected output is,

```
query[((Values.attribute=="1") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like(%a%)))]
.add(query[(Values.attribute=="3") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like(%b%))])
.add(query[(Values.attribute=="1") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like(%a%)]))
```

but actual output is,

```
query[(((Values.attribute=="1") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like(%a%)))]
.add(query[(Values.attribute=="3") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like(%b%))))]
.add(query[(Values.attribute=="1") & (cast(Values.value, db.String()).like(%a%)]))
```

observe the parenthesis.

*there must not be and .add() inside query[]*

How do i correct the solution by Ken T.

Comment: Using python default `re` you cannot match nested parentheses.

Comment: what are the other options available

Comment: Use `regex` module for PCRE capability.

Comment: Your second example is inconsistent, each `and` has 2 operands - so for 2 `and`s it should be 4 queries, not 3. You havent wrapped all the statement after the first `add` with `query`. Other way to look at that it that nested `and` should lead to nested `query` according to your explanation. Am I right?

Comment: I checked my use case, query is added only for single operands

Comment: How would it look for `(a=1) and (b=2) or (c=3)` without the parens?

Comment: ```query[(a=1)].add(query[(b=2) or (c=3)])``` or ```query[(a=1) or (c=3)].add(query[(b=2)])```, i think this.  (c=3) could be done "or " with either (a=1) or (b=2)

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: i am still stuck with regexp to find the contents between outermost parentheses of two operands

Comment: @SebastienD, i have added my current approach and progress in my latest edit

Comment: You could count brackets: +1 for opening bracket, -1 for a closing one. When 0 you found a sub-block you can parse recursively. But I think using some parser library is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive! This is a recursive problem.

```
import re

def queryGen(text, lastOP=''):
    pattern = re.compile("\((.+?)\)\s+(and|or)+\s\((.+)\)")
    res = pattern.search(text)
    
    if not res:
        if lastOP == 'or':
            return text
        elif lastOP == 'and':
            return f'query[{text}]'


    if res.group(2)=='and':
        return f"query[({res.group(1)})].add({queryGen(res.group(3), lastOP='and')})"
    if res.group(2)=='or':
        return f"query[({res.group(1)}) or ({queryGen(res.group(3), lastOP='or')})]"

        
        

print(queryGen("(a=1) and ((b=2) or (c=3))"))
print(queryGen("(a=1) and ((b=2) and (c=3))"))
print(queryGen("""((Attributes.name=="usertype") & (cast(User_Values.value, db.String())=='"Employee"')) and (((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"type":"examplecom"}]))) or ((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"value":"exampleorg"}]))))"""))
```

Return:

```
query[(a=1)].add(query[(b=2) or (c=3)])
query[(a=1)].add(query[(b=2)].add(query[c=3]))
query[((Attributes.name=="usertype") & (cast(User_Values.value, db.String())=='"Employee"'))].add(query[((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"type":"examplecom"}]))) or ((Attributes.name=="emails") & (User_Values.value.contains([{"value":"exampleorg"}])))])
```

You can test the regular expression pattern interactively at the following website:

https://regex101.com/r/C1GFuS/1

Comment: I have noticed one problem with this solution. Please have to look at my latest edit.

Comment: for input, ```"(a=1) and ((b=2) and (c=3))"```, the solution is correct, but if we reverse it like ```"((b=2) and (c=3)) and (a=1)"``` the solution is incorrect.  It gives ```query[((b=2)].add(query[c=3)) and (a=1])```. which is incorrect. and expected solution is,   ```query[(b=2)].add(query[(c=3)]).add(query[(a=1)])```

Comment: and there cannot be and() inside query[]

Comment: @Mohan that's the reason why it is so important to chose good examples in the question. This solution worked for all examples originally posted, but I doubt it can be modified easily to meet the new requirements, due to the limitations of the regular expression.

Comment: there are many possible example's, unfortunately I noticed this recently

Comment: @Wups, is there any other approaches?